# Spark: Memory not released after unpersist

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory, dataset, persistent-storage

Very simply I use spark 2.4.3 on a 17 node cluster and I have a Dataset which I persist. At the end, after some calculations/actions, I use unpersist() but the Dataset remains in memory at the end according to the storage tab in Spark UI. Even if I use unpersist(true) the Dataset is still there in the end. Why is this happening?

[image: storage]

Comment: can you please provide code as well for better clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Eventually the problem was in the code. I was persisting the Dataset which name was df and then droping columns or changing names of columns and re-assigned it on the same name(df). I guess that means that at the end when I was unpersisting, only the new Dataset was unpersisted(although it was never persisted on the first place). I just persisted the Dataset after the "dropping columns etc" and problem solved.